# How can I get all folders that contain the images using MediaStore?

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm getting all images from the user gallery using this code:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(requireContext().getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(cursor.getString(0));
}
```

I want to ask how can I get all folders that contain the above images using [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore)?

I googled before posting this question to avoid the duplicated questions but I did not find anything as I want, I found related questions but it is for Android 10 and above.

Thank you.

Comment: .DATA gives you full path: Path to folder plus file name. What do you need more?

Comment: @blackapps I found the solution, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all folders of images using this way

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(
        requireContext().getContentResolver(),
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME});

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.w("G183", cursor.getString(0));
}
```

You can handle all folders in your way and remove the duplicated folders.

---

**But there is something very weird**

`MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` Added in API level 29 but at the same time, it's working on API levels under 29. How?

I discovered the solution by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115097/17839308) because if you noticed the answer posted in 2014 and android 10 released in 2020 so I said how he used `MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` in 2014 but this added in 2020!